# How do I get the children of my HorizontalScrollView to FILL THE SCREEN while still not overlapping each other?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FDE0DFDF"
        tools:context=".Main4Activity">


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/alfa_slab_one"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="33sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/alfa_slab_one"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="33sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/alfa_slab_one"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="33sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
          </HorizontalScrollView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

I want to put these textViews horizontaly into the linearlayout but I want ONLY 1 to fill the screen at a time...(afterwards I am going to create a button to scroll to the desired textView.)
I have tried using gravity as well as layout_weight to achieve this - to no success. I've never used Scroll Views before and have spent hours researching online until I decide just to post this and hope for an answer that helps...thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set the HorizontalScrollView element width programatically using full screen width**

Using match_parent for width won't work in case of HorizontalScrollView.

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    int width=getScreenWidth(Main2Activity.this);

    int childCount=linearLayout.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0;i<childCount;i++){
        TextView tv= (TextView ) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        tv.setWidth(width);
    }
}
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
    WindowManager wm= (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    return dm.widthPixels;
  }

}
```

Comment: I just did - just had to test it out first.